# Error when loading many images from database - Android

Tags: android, sql, image

Well... I have an app with lots of images. These images are stored in sdcard. I retrieve them through SQL requests.

So, for example, he is a typical SQL:

```
    SELECT * FROM `table` 
    WHERE 
    tags like 
    '%verb%'
```

The code above will return all images with a tag like "verb". This results in 84 images.

Then, I do a loop to insert this images in a list with name, tags, etc. Here is the code:

```
if (cursorImagens.getCount() > 0) {
    telaScroll.removeAllViews();
    lTodasImagens.removeAllViews();
    for (int i = 0; (i < cursorImagens.getCount()) ; i++) {
        TextView textoNome;
        TextView textoTags;
        LinearLayout linha;
        linha = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.imgsinternas, lTodasImagens, false);
        final ImageButton figuraBotao;
        figuraBotao = (ImageButton) linha.findViewById(R.id.figura);
        figuraBotao.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(PATH + cursorImagens.getString(4) + ".png"));
        final Uri uriImagem = Uri.parse(PATH + cursorImagens.getString(4) + ".png");
        textoNome = (TextView) linha.findViewById(R.id.txtNome);
        textoTags = (TextView) linha.findViewById(R.id.txtTags);
        textoNome.setText(cursorImagens.getString(4));
        textoTags.setText(cursorImagens.getString(3));
        figuraBotao.setOnTouchListener(new Button.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent arg1) {
                if (arg1.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){                           
                    currImageURI = uriImagem;
                    imgItem.setImageURI(uriImagem);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });                             

        lTodasImagens.addView(linha);
        View linhaHorizontal;

        linhaHorizontal = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.linhahorizontalstyle, lTodasImagens, false);
        lTodasImagens.addView(linhaHorizontal);                             
        cursorImagens.moveToNext();
    }
    telaScroll.addView(lTodasImagens);
}
```

When I run this code with the parameter above "verb", it retrieves 84 registers and I got an FC.

What do you guys suggest me to do?

Any help is appreciatted!

Comment: which error? please post log cat

Comment: Sorry... error is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. It's like I said... since I am loading 84 imagebuttons with its images. So, is there a way I can avoid this kind of error to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your images are too big, you'll have to scale them down before setting them as a Drawable. Try using

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(InputStream is, Rect outPadding, Options opts)
```

with an appropirate `opts.inSampleSize` (for instance, 2 will scale down your images to half size) and then creating your drawable like this:

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(yourBitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to save all images in sdcard.Then make one table in database and store all path of images in That TABLE.if you want to show image then create Bitmap from string path and set to images.After setting recycle that bitmap(to garbage collection).

As saving image as blob in data base is very painful and time consuming.Its recommended that if you have more image save into sdcard and save path to `TABLE`.

You will get lots of tutorial on saving and displaying images from sdard

Comment: Hello Sameer, that's exactly what I am doing. I am recording just images paths in my database and all images are saved in sdcard. Problem happens when I have too many registers from database. I got an outOfMemoryError when I load all the images. So, what's the best way to load many images without getting this error?